# Removed Apache2 and installed NginX, still get Apache default page

Tags: web-server, apache-httpd

I am trying to remove Apache2 and replace with NginX.  I purged Apache2 and if I try again, it says "Package 'apache2' is not installed, so not removed".  However, when I go to the localhost page, I'm still get the default Apache page.  I am not sure where to go now.

Comment: Burn the fresh OS image to the SD card. To avoid problems in future install Docker and run Nginx in a container. Really... What's the point of digging in dirt?

Answer (score 2):

Change directory to `/var/www/`

```
cd /var/www/
ls -la
```

you should see these files

```
index.html     index.nginx-debian.html
```

**index.html** is that default page of **apache**. Remove it, then you will see nginx default home page.

Open localhost once again (ctrl+f5)