# Raspberry pi showing nginx welcome page on local IP after uninstall

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, nginx

I have been fiddling with nginx to make a reverse proxy for Deluge with no avail on my Raspberry Pi 3 running the latest version of raspbian. So, I attempt to uninstall it. I did the usual thing, `sudo apt-get remove nginx` followed by `sudo apt-get purge nginx` and `sudo apt-get autoremove` and ending with a reboot for safe measure. So then, I go to my local IP 192.168.1.9, and I see this:
[image]
I find that other people have the same issue, but none that are exactly the same as mine. I tried removing everything related to nginx. 
I have tried:

- `sudo apt-get remove nginx nginx-common` followed by `sudo apt-get
  purge nginx nginx-common`
- `sudo apt-get remove --purge nginx*`
- `sudo apt-get remove nginx-core nginx-full nginx-light nginx-extras nginx-naxsi nginx-common` followed by purging all of these
- I have tried looking at all the ports that are being used/listened by my Pi, and nothing showed up that would point to port 80, or nginx.
- I even tried removing the HTML file that is being displayed on my local IP located in `/var/www/html`, and THAT DIDN'T EVEN WORK. (I got this method from [this](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/59552/removed-apache2-and-installed-nginx-still-get-apache-default-page) guide)

This program has caused me a lot of frustration, and I just want it gone.

I can provide any additional information if necessary.

Thanks!

Comment: `I find that other people have the same issue` - nobody else has any issue removing nginx that I can find - perhaps you're browser or something else on your non raspberry pi computer is at fault - because, you've definitely uninstalled nginx .... try to execute `ps ax | grep nginx` - the only output will be `grep nginx`

Comment: I did the command you mentioned, and I got this: `5588 pts/1 S+ 0:00 grep --color=auto nginx` it's interesting because I have been doing everything remotely, and on my laptop the welcome screen pops up with no fail, but when I'm on my phone I don't get anything.

Comment: so, nginx is successfully uninstalled - your issue is with your laptop